# Python: get parent list

Tags: python, list, numpy

Is there a way to get the parent list, if some element is given? For instance, I have two lists `a` and `b`, and I want

```
def func(a,b):
    mx = max(a[0], b[0]);
    mn = min(a[0], b[0]);
    return (the list that corresponds to (mx, mn) in the order)
```

Edit: for the above example, a simple `if` `else` is enough; but I wonder how to do it if I am dealing with many lists, and want to return, say, the name of the lists in the order of comparison? One solution I can come up with is use `numpy` sorting, which uses `n log(n)` sorting algorithms. Is there faster way?

Edit: Probably using `numpy` sorting is the way.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying. You want to sort lists? Your code doesn't seem to sort lists. In addition why you need to use `numpy`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. But you can get the list corresponding the maximum of the first elements, with [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), like this

```
a, b = [1, 2], [2, 1]
c = a if a[0] > b[0] else b
print c
# [2, 1]
```

So, your function can be written as

```
def func(a,b):
    return a if a[0] > b[0] else b
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I am dealing with a large number of list, and after comparing certain elements, I would like to return the list that corresponds to the largest element, the `if` `else` seems not convenient.

Comment: @Lelouch Can you please explain with an example? There might be a way to do what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `numpy`, simply use [`argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) and `argmax`.

```
def func(a,b):
    lists = (a, b)
    vals = np.array([a[0], b[0]])
    return ( lists[np.argmax(vals)], lists[np.argmin(vals)] )
```

This can easily be generalised to more than two lists, and if all lists are of the same length, `func` can elegantly work on a 2dim array, e.g.:

```
def func(arr):
    return ( arr[np.argmax(arr[:,0])], arr[np.argmin(arr[:,0])] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key parameter of the max function.

```
import operator
def func(a,b):
    return max(a, b, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```